# How to show section descriptions in page layout?

Tags: page-layout

I have a simple page layout that contains four sections to be filled out by the user.

Example:

- Heading 1
- (field to filled in by user)
- Heading 2
- (field to be filled in by user)

..etc

What I would like to do is show the column descriptions when the page is in edit mode so that the user has some idea of what kind of info should go in each field. The idea is that there would be basic instructions for adding certain content to help those users that are not very familiar with using SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you in your pagelayout are using `SharePointWebControls` they have a property called `InputFieldLabel` in which you can write some text in which will appear above the control in EditMode.

Example:

```
<SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" FieldName="PageContentDescription" InputFieldLabel="Write a short text here descriping the content of the page." />
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: InputFieldLabel was in the right direction, but with some research about it, I found the "Text" property. This property puts default text into the field, which makes for a clean design. The drawback is that the user has to delete this text or else it shows up when the page is saved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the description as the default text in the sections. Once the user goes in Edit Mode, he can overwrite the default text with the actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried using the [InputFormSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.inputformsection.aspx), I used it everywhere in my solution when user input is required. Check out this [blog](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/inputformsectionascx-control/) to know more.